# ReactRedux, Console log doesn't work in the callback I pass in the setInterval function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I set a interval that triggers `tick()` function every second, inside of it  `addTwo` action changes `count`, a numberic variable in my state. It seems to work but when I put a `console.log` to print  `count` in the same function I call `addTwo` the value don't gets updated, the node containing the value changes, but the initial value (0) gets printed in the console and it doesn't change.

```
const {createStore} = Redux;
const {Provider, connect} = ReactRedux;

const reducer = (state = {count: 0}, action) =>{
    if (action.type == 'ADD-TWO'){
    return{
        count: state.count + 2,
    }
  }else{
    return state;
  }
}

const addTwo = () =>({
    type: 'ADD-TWO',
})

const store = createStore(reducer);

const App = ({count, addTwo}) =>{
  
  const tick = () =>{
    addTwo();
    console.log(count);
  }
  
  const start = () => {
    window.timerID = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  }
  
    return(
    <>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={start}>Press me!</button>
    </>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state;

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    addTwo,
}

const AppContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(App);
 
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Click [here](https://codepen.io/akafadam/pen/ExymzYQ) to see the code in codepen

Comment: This is what's called a "stale closure".  The `setInterval` gets a version of `tick` which always has the initial value.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Can I fix it passing count as argument?

Comment: Looks like you fixed it?  The log is delayed by one tick, but I think that's just due to the nature of `addTwo` being asynchronous.

Comment: It changes now, but the it gets triggerd only when I press the button, setInterval doesn't seem to work.